# Index out of Range Error with Custom TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have two TableViews, both of which are Custom. One of those is a Custom TableView with a Header cell. The second one is a custom TableView without a header cell. What I am trying to do is when someone taps on the first tableView, the tapped item gets added to the second TableView. The problem is when I try to add the second item, the app crashes with an Index Out Of Range Fatal Error. This is in Swift 3.

Here is my Code:

```
    import UIKit

struct TableData {

    var section: String = ""

    var data = Array<String>()

    var dataS = Array<String>()

    init(){}

}

var data = Array<TableData>()
var wordData = Array<TableData>()

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var labelS: UILabel!

}

class MyCustomWordCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var wordLabelS: UILabel!

}

class MyCustomHeader: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var header: UILabel!

}

class TypeViewController: BaseViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var wordTableView: UITableView!

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.tableView {
            return data[section].data.count
        }

        if tableView == self.wordTableView {
            return wordData.count
        }

        return 0
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.tableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
            cell.label.text = data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
            cell.labelS.text = data[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]
            return cell

        }

        if tableView == self.wordTableView {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WordCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomWordCell

            if wordData.count != 0 {
                if wordData.count > indexPath.row {
                    cell.wordLabel.text = wordData[indexPath.row].data[0]
                    cell.wordLabelS.text = wordData[indexPath.row].dataS[0]
                }
            }
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.tableView {

            return 7

        } else {

            return 1

        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        if tableView == self.tableView {

            let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Header") as! MyCustomHeader

            headerCell.header.text = data[section].section

            return headerCell

        }

        return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Header")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if tableView == self.tableView {

            var element: TableData

            element = TableData()

            element.data.append(data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]);

            element.dataS.append(data[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]);

            wordData.append(element)

            wordTableView.reloadData()

            if wordData.count == 3 {

                performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFind", sender: self)

            }

        }

        if tableView == self.wordTableView {

            wordData.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            wordTableView.reloadData()

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSlideMenuButton()
        addItems()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func addItems() {

        var new_elements:TableData

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj1);
        new_elements.data.append(obj2);
        new_elements.data.append(obj3);
        new_elements.data.append(obj4);
        new_elements.data.append(obj5);
        new_elements.data.append(obj6);
        new_elements.data.append(obj7);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS1);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS2);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS3);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS4);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS5);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS6);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS7);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj11);
        new_elements.data.append(obj12);
        new_elements.data.append(obj13);
        new_elements.data.append(obj14);
        new_elements.data.append(obj15);
        new_elements.data.append(obj16);
        new_elements.data.append(obj17);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS11);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS12);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS13);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS14);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS15);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS16);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS17);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj21);
        new_elements.data.append(obj22);
        new_elements.data.append(obj23);
        new_elements.data.append(obj24);
        new_elements.data.append(obj25);
        new_elements.data.append(obj26);
        new_elements.data.append(obj27);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS21);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS22);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS23);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS24);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS25);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS26);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS27);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj31);
        new_elements.data.append(obj32);
        new_elements.data.append(obj33);
        new_elements.data.append(obj34);
        new_elements.data.append(obj35);
        new_elements.data.append(obj36);
        new_elements.data.append(obj37);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS31);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS32);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS33);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS34);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS35);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS36);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS37);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj41);
        new_elements.data.append(obj42);
        new_elements.data.append(obj43);
        new_elements.data.append(obj44);
        new_elements.data.append(obj45);
        new_elements.data.append(obj46);
        new_elements.data.append(obj47);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS41);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS42);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS43);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS44);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS45);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS46);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS47);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj51);
        new_elements.data.append(obj52);
        new_elements.data.append(obj53);
        new_elements.data.append(obj54);
        new_elements.data.append(obj55);
        new_elements.data.append(obj56);
        new_elements.data.append(obj57);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS51);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS52);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS53);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS54);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS55);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS56);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS57);

        data.append(new_elements)

        new_elements = TableData()
        new_elements.section = "Name"
        new_elements.data.append(obj61);
        new_elements.data.append(obj62);
        new_elements.data.append(obj63);
        new_elements.data.append(obj64);
        new_elements.data.append(obj65);
        new_elements.data.append(obj66);
        new_elements.data.append(obj67);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS61);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS62);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS63);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS64);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS65);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS66);
        new_elements.dataS.append(objS67);

        data.append(new_elements)


    }

}
```

The line where the error is given is the following:

```
if wordData.count > indexPath.row {

                 cell.wordLabel.text = wordData[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row] //This one


                    cell.wordLabelS.text = wordDataS[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]

                }
```

Attached are some Photos of the MainStoryboard:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s5k50ubas8wewo8/AACTkAsPDtgbOk3EOrb0LeDJa?dl=0

Comment: Which line gives the out of range exception?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. The line has been added.

Comment: It should be `wordData[indexPath.section].count`

Comment: If I do that, it says TableData has no value of type count

Comment: It does let me do this though: wordData[indexPath.section].data.count

Comment: Yes, that is it. In your original code you were taking the count of the outer array (sections) instead of the data in that sections' array. I would also suggest you create a struct to store your data, having two array properties rather than separate arrays that are "related"

Comment: After changing that line, I am unable to add more than 1 object in the wordListView, I want to add 3 objects

Answer (score 0):

You data structures aren't really helping you here, but your problem is in using `indexPath.section` in your `cellForRow:at:` function for the `wordTableView`.

This function should use `wordData[indexPath.row].data[0]`:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == self.tableView { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell    
        cell.label.text = data[indexPath.section].data[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelS.text = dataS[indexPath.section].dataS[indexPath.row]   
        return cell

    }

    if tableView == self.wordTableView {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WordCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomWordCell

        if wordData.count != 0 {
            if wordData.count > indexPath.row {
                cell.wordLabel.text = wordData[indexPath.row].data[0]            
                cell.wordLabelS.text = wordDataS[indexPath.row].dataS[0]      
            }        
        }
        return cell          
    }
    return UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")    
}
```

Also, your `numberOfRowsInSection` is incorrect. It should be:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.tableView {   
        return data[section].data.count
    }

    if tableView == self.wordTableView {
        return wordData.count
    }

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still I am only able to add 1 item to the WordList. Could it be a problem in the didSelectRowAtPath code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I also had to fix your `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Your life would be easier if your data source for your `wordTableView` was just `var wordTableData = TableData()` as then this single structure would contain both `wordLabel` and `wordLabelS` arrays

Comment: I did as you have told me. Please check my updated code. I am still only able to add 1 word to the wordList, I think there is an issue in the didSelectRowAtPath which is causing only 1 word to get added, and limiting it from adding 3 words.

Comment: One issue still remains after all the editing, wordData has 3 elements, because my segue code gets executed, but they are not displayed. Any Ideas? I added a print(wordData) statement to my if wordData.count == 3 statement and it is printing 3 elements. Why are those elements not displayed?

Comment: Here is my version of your code (I had to modify it because I didn't have your full project, but it should give you the idea) - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/30c0ed7dd19be183d38b96baa646d13b

Comment: Where do you expect them to be displayed?  Your are segueing to another view, does that view use the same data?

Comment: Thanks so much Paul, your corrections have helped me fix the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, my other view uses the same data. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I see that you downvoted my question, may I please know why?

Comment: It wasn't me. Anyone could have downvoted it.  It was probably because your question didn't (initially) indicate which line had the array bounds issue and it has a large amount of code. It is best to take the time to provide only the relevant section of code that has the problem.  Also putting photos in dropbox rather than inserting them in your question directly makes it harder for people (As a low-rep user your photos will initially be links but a higher rep user will typically embed them via an edit shortly after you post)

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I am pretty new to StackOverFlow so I sometimes forget to indicate some of the things. Also, I made the Android Version of this app myself with no help but on the iOS version, I struggled a little since I am newer to iOS than I am to android. Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, just one more question, I was fixing up some auto layout issues on the app and one more issue is there. When I click View as iPhone SE for example in XCode 8, 2 of the views stay in iPhone 7 Size while 2 of them switch to the iPhone SE size. If you don't get it, I can send you a video of the issue. Thanks

Comment: You just need to check the constraints for top/left/bottom/right. Also check with the simulator as well as in Interface Builder.  If you can't resolve it then ask another question.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Thanks for the help!